# Multiplying two numbers of the form x.xxxxxxe-x*10^xx is not working properly

Tags: julia

I am trying to evaluate the following example inside my code, but getting the wrong answer:

```
julia> -1.259237254330301e-29*10^29 
-9.930838679817422e-11
```

The answer is clearly wrong, -1.259237254330301 is expected.
I got the right answer by

```
julia> -1.259237254330301e-29*1e29
-1.2592372543303008
```

anyone know the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: This Q&A explains the perils of floating point arithmetic in general.

Comment: [Why does Julia use native machine integer arithmetic?](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/faq/#Why-does-Julia-use-native-machine-integer-arithmetic?-1)

Comment: This is clearly not a duplicate of "Is floating point math broken?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Despite the rounding errors of Floats, the cause for the wrong result comes from the use of Integer Arithmetic with overflow in the Type:
On a 64-Bit OS 10^29 overflows (in JULIA without an error).

```
64-Bit OS: 10^18 =  = 1000000000000000000  (64-Bit Integers can hold up to ~ 9,22x10^18)

while: 10^19 turns to: -8446744073709551616 which is wrong, due to overflowing.
```

If you choose a type capabale of holding the value the result is correct:
eg.:

```
julia> -1.259237254330301e-29*Int128(10)^29
-1.2592372543303008
```

or:

```
julia> -1.259237254330301e-29*big(10)^29
-1.259237254330300936796903330938514872571882315563023692882767533667837970629477
```